# Merge tags trusted-root-certificates and trusted-root-ca

Tags: discussion, tags

I can't really tell the difference between [trusted-root-certificates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trusted-root-certificates) and [trusted-root-ca](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trusted-root-ca). There are some minor technical differences, like in PKIX, a CA requires `basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE`. But I'm not sure the technical minutiae warrants a separate tag.

Perhaps these should be merged into the most obvious one, and then make the unneeded one a synonym for the one that is selected. I would suggest using [trusted-root-certificates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trusted-root-certificates), and making [trusted-root-ca](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trusted-root-ca) a synonym.

Comment: Sounds like both should be merged into some other tag.

Comment: Such as "trusted-certificates"? There's nothing inherently unique about a "root" certificate. It just happens to be at the root.

Comment: Or maybe just "certificates"? Trusted certificates are just trusted "certificates".